# How to focus a text field when the page gets loaded in React using createRef()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I'm able to achieve this functionality only when i invoke my function manually. Used componentDidMount() in my case to bring focus on the input element when the page loads, but no luck. Sharing my code -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class RefsDemo2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    // this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput(){
      this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <input type="text" ref={this.textInput}></input>
          {/* <input type="button" onClick={this.focusTextInput} value="Focus this input"/> */}
          {/* <input type="button" ref={this.focusTextInput} value="Focus this input"/> */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default RefsDemo2
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you prefer to use class components instead of functional components + hooks?

Comment: @JesúsGuillénYparrea - Just started off with react, getting to know the class components first, will surely move to functional components soon!

Comment: Great! I hope you enjoy using React. I just posted an answer below that should make your code work.

Answer (score 0):

please use Can Try This -

```
import React, { Component,useEffect } from 'react'

export class RefsDemo2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    // this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput(){
      this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
        document.getElementById("myInput").focus();
  },[])

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <input id="myInput" type="text" ref={this.textInput}></input>
          {/* <input type="button" onClick={this.focusTextInput} value="Focus this input"/> */}
          {/* <input type="button" ref={this.focusTextInput} value="Focus this input"/> */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default RefsDemo2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @prakash . I have recently started off with React, Is there any way that we could do this with class components?

Comment: I think it is a bad practice to use useEffect hook along with the other component cycle functions like componentDidMount . Also, we should avoid the usage of DOM Api directly, instead React provides createRef or useRef (when using hooks).

Answer (score 0):

Please, avoid using document.getElementById or any DOM query directly as the other answer suggested. This should work (as it is coming from the oficial documentation):

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.focusTextInput();
  }    
  
  render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
    // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={this.textInput} />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Focus the text input"
          onClick={this.focusTextInput}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, you were pretty close, but you needed to also bind the function to focus the input with ref before using it.

Edit:
This is the stackblitz example working [Stackblitz](https://react-yvmnof.stackblitz.io) and editor [Editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yvmnof?file=src/App.js)

Comment: This is giving me runtime errors in the console - "Uncaught TypeError: this.textInput.current.focusTextInput is not a function". Could u pls share a running stackblitz / codepen example for this?

Comment: i just updated my answer to include an example. Sorry, i saw that there was a bit wrong in the code, i also corrected the example in the answer.